# selecting nearby hexes around a hex

Tags: javascript, html4, hexagonal-tiles

I'm trying to select all hexes in a given range. However I'm getting weird results while implement this code found on Amit Patel's [page](http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#range).

```
var results = []
for each -N ≤ dx ≤ N:
    for each max(-N, -dx-N) ≤ dy ≤ min(N, -dx+N):
        var dz = -dx-dy
        results.append(cube_add(center, Cube(dx, dy, dz)))
```

This is what I have so far:

```
    var center = this._cel.copy( hex.coords );
    var dx = range - center.q;
    var dy = range - center.r;

    var results = [];

    for (var q = -range; q <= dx; q++ ) {
        var r1 = Math.max(-range, -q - range);
        var r2 = Math.min(range, -q + range);
        for ( var r = r1; r <= r2; r++ ) {
            //console.log( q, r, -q-r )
            var c = new Cell(q, r, -q-r) 
            results.push( c.add( center ) );
        }
    }
```

I suppose that the loop constrains need to me a little bit amended and make use of the dx, dy values.

```html
<body>
 <canvas width="420px" height="420px" id="myCanvas" style="margin:0; padding:0; border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
</body>

<script id="hexagon">
function Point( pos ) {
    this.x = 0;
 this.y = 0;
 if( typeof( pos ) !== "undefined" ){
  this.x = pos[0];
  this.y = pos[1];
 }
};

function Cell( _q, _r, _s ){ //// direction ///
 this.q = _q;
 this.r = _r;
 this.s = _s;
 this._hashID = null;
 this.generateHashID();
}

Cell.prototype = {
 constructor: Cell,
 add: function( d ){
  this.q += d.q;
  this.r += d.r;
  this.s += d.s;
  this.generateHashID();
  return this;
 },
 copy: function( c ){
  this.set( c.q, c.r, c.s );
  return this;
 },
 set: function( _q, _r, _s ){
  this.q = _q;
  this.r = _r;
  this.s = _s;
  this.generateHashID();
  return this;
 },
 generateHashID: function(){
  this._hashID = this.q+"."+this.r+"."+this.s;
 },
 getHashID: function(){
  return this._hashID;
 },
 round: function(){
  var q = Math.trunc(Math.round(this.q));
  var r = Math.trunc(Math.round(this.r));
  var s = Math.trunc(Math.round(this.s));
  var q_diff = Math.abs(q - this.q);
  var r_diff = Math.abs(r - this.r);
  var s_diff = Math.abs(s - this.s);
  if (q_diff > r_diff && q_diff > s_diff){
   q = -r - s;
  }else if (r_diff > s_diff){
   r = -q - s;
  }else{
   s = -q - r;
  }
  
  return this.set( q, r, s );
 }
}

var Hex = function( coords, l_ ){ //// [axial], [cartesian] , layout
 this.coords = new Cell( coords[0], coords[1], coords[2] );
 
 this.content = -2;
 
 this.pos = this.coords; //// set primary coorinate type ///
 
 this.neighbors = [];
 
 this.layout = l_;
 this.corners = [];
 
 this.center = this.get_center_p();
 
 //this.id = this.generate_id( cart_coord );

 this.colors = {
  "base" : {
   filling : "#008844",
   border : "#FFDD88",
  },
  "selected": {
   filling: "#00cc00"
  },
  "hovered": {
   filling: "#006600"
  },
  "path" : {
   filling: "#80ff00"
  },
  "obstacle" : {
   filling: "#86592d"
  },
  "neighbor": {
   filling: "#ffbf00"
  }
 }
 
 this.states = {
  "selected" : false,
  "hovered" : false,
  "isPath": false,
  "isObstacle": false,
  "isNeighbor": false
 }

 this.generate_corners();
};

Hex.prototype = {
 constructor: Hex,

 get_corner_offset: function( corner ){
  var angle = 2.0 * Math.PI * (corner + this.layout.orientation.start_angle) / 6;
  return new Point( [ size.x * Math.cos(angle), size.y * Math.sin(angle) ] );
 },
 
 generate_corners: function( h ){
  var offset = null, angle = 0;
  var size = this.layout.size;
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
   angle = 2.0 * Math.PI * (i + this.layout.orientation.start_angle) / 6;
   offset = new Point( [ size.x * Math.cos(angle), size.y * Math.sin(angle )] );
   
   this.corners.push( 
    new Point( [ this.center.x + offset.x, this.center.y + offset.y ] )
   );
  }
 },
 
 draw: function( ctx ){
  var points = this.corners;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo( points[0].x, points[0].y );
  for(var i = 1; i < points.length; i++){
   var p = points[i];
   ctx.lineTo(p.x, p.y);
  }
  ctx.closePath();
  ////  fill Hex ///
  if( this.checkState("selected") ){
   ctx.fillStyle = this.colors.selected.filling;
  }else if(  this.checkState("hovered") ){
   ctx.fillStyle = this.colors.hovered.filling;
  }else if(  this.checkState("isPath") ){
   ctx.fillStyle = this.colors.path.filling;
  }else if(  this.checkState("isNeighbor") ){
   ctx.fillStyle = this.colors.neighbor.filling;
  }else if(  this.checkState("isObstacle") ){
   ctx.fillStyle = this.colors.obstacle.filling;
  }else{
   ctx.fillStyle =  this.colors.base.filling;
  }
  ctx.fill();
  //// draw border ///
  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#19334d";
  ctx.stroke();
  
  this.draw_coords( ctx );
  
  this.draw_center_point( ctx );
 },
 
 add_neighbor: function( neighbor ){
  this.neighbors.push( neighbor );
 },
 
 show_neighbors: function(){
  for( var nb = 0, nb_l = this.neighbors.length; nb < nb_l; nb++ ){
   this.neighbors[nb].changeState("isNeighbor", true);
  }
 },
 
 hide_neighbors: function(){
  for( var nb = 0, nb_l = this.neighbors.length; nb < nb_l; nb++ ){
   this.neighbors[nb].changeState("isNeighbor", false);
  }
 },
 
 draw_coords: function( ctx ){
  var text = this.coords.q+" : "+ this.coords.s;
  var text_z =  this.coords.r;
  var metrics1 = ctx.measureText(text);
  var metrics2 = ctx.measureText(text_z);
  var w1 = metrics1.width;
  var w2 = metrics2.width;
  var h = 8;
  ctx.font = h+'pt Calibri bold';
  ctx.textAlign = 'center';
  ctx.fillStyle = '#FFFFFF';
  ctx.fillText(text, this.center.x, this.center.y + (h/2) - 5 );
  ctx.fillText(text_z, this.center.x, this.center.y + (h/2) + 7 );
 },
 
 get_center_p: function(){
  var M = this.layout.orientation;
  var x = ( M.f0 * this.pos.q + M.f1 * this.pos.r ) * this.layout.size.x;
  var y = ( M.f2 * this.pos.q + M.f3 * this.pos.r ) * this.layout.size.y;
  return new Point([
   x + this.layout.origin.x, 
   y + this.layout.origin.y 
  ]);
 },
 
 draw_center_point: function( ctx ){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth="1";
  ctx.fillStyle="red";
  ctx.arc( this.center.x , this.center.y , 2, 0 ,2*Math.PI);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.fill();
 },
 
 generate_id: function( coords ){
  return parseInt( coords[0]+''+coords[1] );
 },
 
 checkState: function( state ){
  return this.states[ state ];
 },
 
 changeState: function( state , value){
  this.states[ state ] = value;
 },
 
 trigger: function( ev_name ){
  if( this.events[ ev_name ] ){
   this.events[ ev_name ].call( this );
  }
 },
 
 setContent: function( type ){
  this.content = type;
  this.changeState( "isObstacle" , true );
 },
 
 hover: function(){
  if( ! this.checkState("isPath") ){
   this.trigger("hover");
  }
 },
 
 clear_hover: function(){
  if( ! this.checkState("isPath") ){
   this.trigger("clear_hover");
  }
 },
 
 select: function(){
  this.trigger("select");
  //this.show_neighbors();
 },
 
 unselect: function(){
  this.trigger("unselect");
 },
 
 events: {
  select: function(){
   this.changeState("selected", true);
   this.changeState("hovered", false);
  },
  unselect: function(){
   this.changeState("selected", false);
  },
  hover: function(){
   this.changeState("hovered", true);
  },
  clear_hover: function(){
   this.changeState("hovered", false);
  }
 }
};


</script>

<script id="grid">

var Grid = function( size, hex_size, origin, ctx_pos, layout_type ){
 this.size = size;
 this.grid_r = size/2;
 
 this.layout_type = layout_type;
 this.layout = this.set_layout( this.layout_types[this.layout_type], hex_size, origin );
 
 this.hexes = [];
 
 this.hovered = [null, null]; //// [cur, prev] ///
 this.selected = [null, null]; ///// [cur , prev] ///
 
 this.dots = [];
 
 this._list = [];
 this._cel = new Cell();
 
 this._directions = [new Cell(+1, 0, -1), new Cell(+1, -1, 0), new Cell(0, -1, +1),
      new Cell(-1, 0, +1), new Cell(-1, +1, 0), new Cell(0, +1, -1)];
 
 this.generate();
 this.add_neighbors();
 
 this.mouse = new Point();
 this.mouse_events( new Point( ctx_pos ) );
}

Grid.prototype = {
 constructor: Grid,
 layout_types: {
  "pointy": [ 
   [ Math.sqrt(3.0), Math.sqrt(3.0) / 2.0, 0.0, 3.0 / 2.0], //// 2x2 forward matrix  
   [ Math.sqrt(3.0) / 3.0, -1.0 / 3.0, 0.0, 2.0 / 3.0], ///// 2x2 inverse matrix 
   0.5
  ], //// starting angle in multiples of 60° /////
  "flat": [ 
   [3.0 / 2.0, 0.0, Math.sqrt(3.0) / 2.0, Math.sqrt(3.0)], //// 2x2 forward matrix  
   [2.0 / 3.0, 0.0, -1.0 / 3.0, Math.sqrt(3.0) / 3.0], ///// 2x2 inverse matrix 
   1.0
  ]
 },
 set_layout: function( orn_type , hex_s_, ogn_  ){
  return {
   orientation: this.set_orientation( orn_type ), ///// orientation type ///
   size: new Point( [ hex_s_ , hex_s_ ] ), ///// hex size ///
   origin: new Point( ogn_ ) //// Grid center /////
  }
 },

 set_orientation: function( opts ){ /// [0] : forward_matrix, [1] : inverse_matrix, [2] : starting_angle
  return {
   f0: opts[0][0], f1: opts[0][1], f2: opts[0][2], f3: opts[0][3], b0: opts[1][0], b1: opts[1][1], b2: opts[1][2], b3: opts[1][3], start_angle: opts[2]
  }
 },
 
 get_hex_at_p: function( p ){ //// point ///
  var M = this.layout.orientation;
  var pt = new Point( [ (p.x - this.layout.origin.x) / this.layout.size.x,  (p.y - this.layout.origin.y) / this.layout.size.y ] );
  var q = M.b0 * pt.x + M.b1 * pt.y;
  var r = M.b2 * pt.x + M.b3 * pt.y;
  var c = this._cel.set( q, r, -q-r );
  return c.round();
 },
 
 generate: function(){
  var n_hex = null; 
  for (var q = -this.grid_r; q <= this.grid_r; q++) {
   var r1 = Math.max(-this.grid_r, -q - this.grid_r);
   var r2 = Math.min(this.grid_r, -q + this.grid_r);
   for (var r = r1; r <= r2; r++) {
    n_hex = new Hex( [ q, r, -q-r ], this.layout );
    this.hexes[ n_hex.coords.getHashID() ] = n_hex;
   }
  }
 },
 
 _selectHexesInRange: function( hex,  range ){
  var center = this._cel.copy( hex.coords );
  var dx = range - center.q;
  var dy = range - center.r;
  
  var results = [];
  for (var q = -range; q <= dx; q++ ) {
   var r1 = Math.max(-range, -q - range);
   var r2 = Math.min(range, -q + range);
   for ( var r = r1; r <= r2; r++ ) {
    var c = new Cell(q, r, -q-r) 
    results.push( c.add( center ) );
   }
  }
  
  for( var h in results){
   if( typeof( this.hexes[results[h].getHashID()]) !== "undefined" ){
     this.hexes[results[h].getHashID()].select()
   }
  }
  //console.log( results )
 },
 
 hex_corner_offset : function ( corner ) {
  var size = this.layout.size;
  var angle = 2.0 * Math.PI * (this.layout.orientation.start_angle - corner) / 6;
  return new Point([size.x * Math.cos(angle), size.y * Math.sin(angle)]);
 },
 
 point_add : function(p, q) {
  return new Point([p.x + q.x, p.y + q.y]);
 },

 add_neighbors: function(){
  var nbor = null, hex = null;
  for( var h in this.hexes ){
   hex = this.hexes[h];
   var i, n, l = this._directions.length;
   this._list.length = 0;//// reset array ///
   for ( i = 0; i < l; i++ ) {
    this._cel.copy( hex.coords );
    this._cel.add( this._directions[i] );
    n = this.hexes[ this._cel.getHashID() ];
    if (typeof(n) == "undefined") { ///// if doesn't exists ////
     this._list.push( null );
     continue;
    }
    this._list.push(n);
   }
   
   hex.neighbors = this._list.slice(); //// take copy of the array ////
  }
 },
 
 draw: function( ctx ){
  for( var h in this.hexes ){
   this.hexes[h].draw( ctx );
  }
 },
 
 checkCollisions: function(){
  var h_pos = this.get_hex_at_p( this.mouse );
  var hex = this.hexes[ h_pos.getHashID() ];
  if( typeof(hex) !== "undefined" ){
   if( this.hovered[0] == null ){ //// cur 
    this.hovered[0] = hex;
    this.hovered[0].hover();
   }else{
    this.hovered[1] = this.hovered[0];
    this.hovered[0] = hex;
    if( this.hovered[0].coords._hashID != this.hovered[1].coords._hashID ){
     this.hovered[1].clear_hover();
     this.hovered[1] = null;
    }
   }
   this.hovered[0].hover();
  }
 },
 
 mouse_events: function( ctx_pos ){
  var self = this;
  
  window.addEventListener( 'mousemove', function(e){
   self.mouse.x = ( e.clientX - ctx_pos.x );
   self.mouse.y = ( e.clientY - ctx_pos.y );
  });
  
  window.addEventListener( 'mousedown', function(e){
   //console.log( "neighbors : ",self.hovered[0].neighbors )
   self._selectHexesInRange( self.hovered[0], 2);
  });
 }
}
</script>

<script id="main">
var c_el = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c_el.getContext("2d");

var nGrid = new Grid( 6, 25, [ c_el.width / 2, c_el.height / 2 ], [c_el.getBoundingClientRect().left, c_el.getBoundingClientRect().top], "pointy" );

function animate(){
 window.requestAnimationFrame( animate );
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c_el.width, c_el.height);
 nGrid.checkCollisions();
 nGrid.draw( ctx);
}

animate();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take the coordinates x, y, z and then search all fields to one of this calculations:

1. z is const, x is plus/minus 1, y is minus/plus 1
2. x is const, z is plus/minus 1, y is minus/plus 1
3. y is const, z is plus/minus 1, x is minus/plus 1

This should be all neighbors

Example: Filed 0, 1, -1 (x,y,z)

1. z is const and x is plus/minus 1 => [-1, 2,-1], [ 1, 0,-1]
2. x is const and z is plus/minus 1 => [ 0, 2,-2], [ 0, 0, 0]
3. y is const and z is plus/minus 1 => [ 1, 1,-2], [-1, 1, 0]

For a faster search you can store your cells inside a Object like this:

```
var cells = new Object();
for(x=-2; x<3; x++){
    cells[x] = new Object();
    for(y=-2; y<3; y++){
        cells[x][y] = new Object();
        for(z=-2; z<3; z++){
            cells[x][y][z] = cell;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can access the cells by there coordinates:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 1;
var z = -1;
var neighbors = new Array();
neighbors.push(cells[x-1][y+1][z]);
neighbors.push(cells[x+1][y-1][z]);
neighbors.push(cells[x][y+1][z-1]);
neighbors.push(cells[x][y-1][z+1]);
neighbors.push(cells[x+1][y][z-1]);
neighbors.push(cells[x-1][y][z+1]);
```

Comment: what? I don't seem to understand..  why would I need to make another array filled with Objects? Each hex is stored in an array and does have a `neighbors` property that consist all surrounding hexes , and also they all contain a cell coordinate. My example is partially working, it just need some slight amendment to the loop constrains.

Comment: Oh, now i see your problem. My calculations make the same like the loop with a distance of 1.